# Multiple entires in one column?

Tags: sql, database

I want to store all the login attempts by ip.

loginAttempts {
ip:
time:
id:
}
etc..

The problem is it is inevitible that one ip will have multiple login attempts, and I understand that it is not good to store multiple values in one column, how can I log login details by ip, without repeating the same ip address?

Comment: you already have a time (DATETIME maybe?) column so surely that will avoid the problem you're concerned about?

Comment: Why dont you try a master-detail construction? The master table could be LoginAttemps, and the detal table LoginDate.

Answer (score 0):

you can either normalise by using more than one table or if you still want that in a single column, you can have a array inside json

```
{
  "ip": "0.0.0.0",
  "loginattempts": [
    "01/01/2016 12:20",
    "01/02/2016 12:30"
  ]
}
```